# Upper bound lemma implies the ergodic theorem for random walks on groups?

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, markov-chains

*Cross-Posted from [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464439/upper-bound-lemma-implies-the-ergodic-theorem-for-random-walks-on-groups).*

> **Ergodic theorem.** A random walk on a finite group $G$ driven by a probability $\nu\in M_p(G)$ is *ergodic* if $\operatorname{supp}(\nu)$ is not concentrated
> on a proper subgroup $S\subset G$ nor the coset of a normal subgroup
> $N\triangleleft G$.

In this case the convolution powers of $\nu$ converge to the uniform distribution $\pi$ on $G$:

$$\nu^{\star k}\rightarrow \pi.$$

Where $\|\cdot \|=\frac12\|\cdot\|_{\ell_1}$,
$$(\nu\star \nu)(g)=\sum_{t\in G}\nu(gt^{-1})\nu(t),$$
$d_\alpha$ is the dimension of a representation $\rho_\alpha:G\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$,
$$\hat{\nu}(\rho)=\sum_{t\in G}\nu(t)\rho(t),$$
and $T^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $T$ in $\operatorname{GL}(V)$, Diaconis & Shahshahani proved the following:

> **Upper bound lemma.** Where $\operatorname{Irr}(G)\backslash \tau$ is the set of non-trivial unitary irreducible representations on $G$:
> $$\|\nu^{\star k}-\pi\|^2\leq \frac{1}{4}\sum_{\rho_\alpha\in \operatorname{Irr}(G)\backslash \tau}d_\alpha \operatorname{Tr}[\widehat{\nu}(\rho_\alpha)^k(\widehat{\nu}(\rho_\alpha)^*)^k].$$

The upper bound lemma still holds if the random walk driven by $\nu$ is not ergodic.

Note that the sum over the non-trivial irreducible representations is *equal* (up to a constant) to $\|\nu^{\star k}-\pi\|_{\ell_2}^2$ and so can detect convergence.

**Question: Can the upper bound lemma be used to prove the ergodic theorem?**

Can the upper bound lemma show that for $\nu^{\star k}$ to converge to $\pi$ it is necessary that $\nu$ is not supported on a subgroup (irreducibility)? I suspect aperiodicity (not concentrated on the coset of normal subgroup) might be harder.

My own [MSc thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05387) should be a good reference for some of this.

**Background:** It is possible to prove an upper bound lemma for finite *quantum* groups, however finding necessary and sufficient conditions for convergence to uniform (convergence to the Haar state) is an open problem (Edit: this is now settled — [The ergodic theorem for random walks on finite quantum groups](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2021.1908551?journalCode=lagb20)). If the upper bound lemma can yield the necessary and sufficient conditions for convergence in the classical case, perhaps something similar might be possible in the quantum case.

Comment: I guess in some sense the upper bound lemma cannot show a necessary condition, by virtue of the very fact that it is an *upper* bound.  But I don't see why you want to use it?  It is trivial that irreducibility and aperiodicity are necessary.  The hard part of the ergodic theorem is the sufficiency.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is an upper bound but equal to a two-norm and so can detect convergence (added). I have also added a little background as to why I am interested in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of necessity.

First suppose $\nu$ is concentrated on a proper subgroup $S$. Then consider the module $\mathbb C[G/S]$.  It is not the trivial module and contains the trivial module with multiplicity $1$.  Therefore, it contains a non-trivial irreducible constituent $\rho_a$.  By Frobenius reciprocity, there is a vector $v$ in the representation space of $\rho_a$ fixed by $S$.  Therefore, any convex combination of elements of $S$ fixes $v$. It follows since $\rho_a$ is unitary that $\widehat{\nu}(\rho_a)^k(\widehat{\nu}(\rho_a)^*)^k$ fixes $v$ and hence has an eigenvalue of $1$ and this will prevent your right hand side, which is the $\ell_2$-norm, from converging to $0$.

Suppose now that it is concentrated on a coset of a proper normal subgroup $N$.  Let $\rho_a$ be a non-trivial irreducible unitary representation of $G/N$, which we view as a representation of $G$.  If $m=[G:N]$, then for any $k>0$, $\widehat{\nu}(\rho_a)^{km}(\widehat{\nu}(\rho_a)^*)^{km}$ is the identity matrix and so its trace will not go to zero.

I’m not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to your answer. Thanks very much: this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. This much may indeed be useful.